# Visual Studio 2013 only showing attach in debug menu

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

I'm a Visual Studio and programming noob so please don't give me some advanced programming lingo that I'm not going to be able to understand.

Earlier today I was programming in C++ (I only started yesterday). But when I reopened VS to continue programming it didn't give me an option to debug, it only said "Attach...".

This is my first post so I'm not allowed to post pictures.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gepn6o9seal2veg/spinglespangle1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio you need to have a solution (.sln) open to build and debug against. You currently only have a single file open, not the solution containing it. You should be able to find the solution in the File->Recent Projects and Solutions menu.

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+S will save the solution (creating it if necessary)

Answer (score 3):

1. Right Click on your solution , select "set startup projects"
2. Opt for Single startup project and select you project
3. Click Apply or OK